# Symmetric product in arbitrary categories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

When I first came along the symmetric product, the definition regarded topological spaces only. But when I engaged more with that topic I saw that it is also used for simplicial sets, for example. So I was wondering whether one can generalise the notion of a symmetric product to arbitrary categories with certain properties.

My first guess would have been that one can define it in all categories where products exist and where one has fixed isomorphisms $\phi\colon X\times Y\to Y\times X$ for all objects $X$ and $Y$. Because in this case one can let a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ act on $X^n$ by splitting it into transpositions of successive numbers and applying the product of $\phi$ with the identities in the proper order several times. Is this true respectively is this sensible? And how about infinite symmetric products? In my point of view, it should then suffice to simply consider basepointed objects in order to be able to define the infinite symmetric product as the colimit in the usual manner. However, I am not too sure about that.

I was thinking about that because I wondered how one can generalise the formula
$$
\operatorname{SP}^n(X\amalg Y) = \coprod_{k=0}^n \operatorname{SP}^k(X)\times \operatorname{SP}^{n-k}(Y).
$$

Comment: What is the motivating example of this "symmetric product"? Something from linear algebra, maybe?

Comment: If by $\times$ you mean categorical product, then there always is a canonical isomorphism $\times  \xrightarrow{\cong} ×$. So you can define the (infinite) symmetric product in any category with products and colimits. But the last formula depends on the distributive law $X\times(Y\coprod Z)\cong X\times Y \coprod X\times Z$, and this does not hold in every category. In general, the last formula will hold in a cartesian closed category. Or more generally in a closed symmetric  monoidal category, if you replace product with the relevant monoidal structure.

Comment: @GregoryArone Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. One also needs to demand that the objects are sets, right? Because otherwise I do not see how one can divide out a group action.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I encountered it in the Dold-Thom theorem for the first time. I think that is one of its main applications.

Comment: @Georgonzola Division by a group action is a colimit. You can make sense of it in any category with direct limits.